# During data import Access doesn't recognize all of the named_ranges available in excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, database, microsoft-access, import

As I described in the subject, during importing Excel file into an Access made database I'm facing an issue of Access not seeing all of the named_ranges I created in my Excel file.

This is the data I want to import.

[image: This is the data I want to import.]

There is few named ranges in this workbook I'm using to create the data that I'm importing later into Access. And up until now I've been using "print_areas" as named_range I was passing through to Access import wizard during the import process.

These are the named ranges in my Excel file.

Up until now print_areas were working fine and I've used them to point, precisely which data I want to import to Access. 
While in the external data import wizard in Access, I wasn't choosing whole excel worksheets to import. I was choosing previously set "print_ares" to precisely select data I want to import.

These are the named ranges in my Excel file:

[image]

Up until now I was using these other print_areas and it was working fine but now this specific "print_area" in the "checkouts" sheet is not visible in Access's external data source import wizard.

These are the named ranges I can choose while importing data into Access:

[image: These are the named ranges I can choose while importing data into Access.]

Not all of the named_ranges I've created in excel file are available for me to choose in the Access external data import wizard.
Why some of these named_ranges are available and some are not, even if they are named_ranges of the same type, for example print_areas in different sheets.

Why none of my tables names I have in excel file are not visible as named_ranges in the Access external data import wizard.
Aren't the tables some special kind of named_range in Excel file.
They do have a name - don't they.
If so, I should be able to see them as named_ranges in the Access external data import wizard, and I should be able to select them and move forward.

I've been here [Named ranges (defined names) do not appear in Access on - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/named-ranges-defined-names-do-not-appear-in-access/6443bfff-66b6-4720-9cde-26e62a0011b7) and I've read it 3 times, but there is no answer that solves my problem.